# Filter White Noise from Recording

Tags: c#, audio-recording, naudio

I'm using the C# library NAudio to record voice input.

Other posts have suggested a "Noise gate", and while this *may* help, it is currently nowhere near sufficient.

**How can I filter the white noise from a recording in C#?**

Comment: Ordinary white noise or pink noise is incoherent: there's no pattern you can latch onto to remove it.  Hum filters work because you have a fundamental frequency and harmonics that you can notch out.

Comment: How can I make the recording clear enough so that is can be recognized by, say, Google Speech API?

Comment: By improving your equipment, changing the environment, getting the correct distance to the microphone, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in my creating a WaveFormat() instance.

Apparently when using 8-bit PCM, you should expect poor sound quality.

```
waveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 8, 1);
```

However, by changing it to 16-bit, the quality greatly improved.

```
waveFormat = new WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would ideally like a band-pass filter which NAudio doesn't provide functionality for.  Here's a link I found on a possible [work around using a BiQuadFilter](https://naudio.codeplex.com/discussions/402281).  I believe you could also apply both a high and low pass filter to achieve the same results.  You might have to play with the settings to get what you want.

Hope this helps.